# How to suppress Xcode "Attribute Unavailable" warning in XIB file?

Tags: xcode, macos, warnings, xib

My App is targeted to 10.6 and the "Deployment" value for all .xib files was 10.6 apart from one, which recently changed to 10.7 (I don't know when).  If I change it back to 10.6 I get the following warning from Xcode:

```
/Users/andy/Source/.../Preferences.xib:383: Identifier on OS X versions prior to 10.7
```

Here is the relevant part of the .xib file:

```
381: <string key="NSFrame">{{1, 1}, {116, 104}}</string>
382: <reference key="NSSuperview" ref="14642427"/>
383: <reference key="NSNextKeyView" ref="1001986100"/>
384: <string key="NSReuseIdentifierKey">_NS:11</string>
```

(In fact when I open the .xib in BBEdit in order to see the warning line and then close it and clean/build in Xcode, the line being warned seems to change; it's always 383 however the content moves.  The last time the warning happened it was the `NSSuperview` line that was on line 383, which is weird to say the least).

Sometimes I get two warnings.  The other warning is:

```
file://localhost/Users/andy/Source/.../Preferences.xib: warning: Attribute Unavailable: Identifier on OS X versions prior to 10.7
```

Which highlights a custom view in the .xib file when I click on it.

Can anyone tell me what this warning means and how I get rid of it?

I am developing under 10.8 using Xcode 4.4.1 and I reckon this warning will cause issues when running under 10.6 (something I cannot do during development).  I am happy to provide additional info, as required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**To remove it:**

1) Select the XIB file (editor opens)

2) Press `cmd`+`opt`+`3` to open the Identity Inspector for the XIB in question. Then press the warning in the warning navigator -- which should select the offending object in the NIB editor.

3) Clear the value in Identity > Identifier (just below the field where you would specify a custom class)

4) Save and Build.

That should do it.

**What it means:**

You are using a document feature which is not supported by 10.6.

Specifically, it appears this key/value is associated to `@protocol NSUserInterfaceItemIdentification`:

> The NSUserInterfaceItemIdentification protocol is used to associate a
>   unique identifier with objects in your user interface. The protocol is
>   adopted by AppKit interface objects to support window restoration,
>   whereby information about window and other interface-related objects
>   is preserved and used to restore the application’s interface during
>   the next launch cycle.

The key to search for in the XIB is `userInterfaceItemIdentifier`.

Comment: Thanks; I'll try that later when I'm back at my Mac.  I  looked at the OS X API differences document to see if I could find out what changed in this area between 10.6 and 10.7 but nothing was obvious.  Do you know where I would find the documentation to show this 10.7+ feature I have turned on?

Comment: Perhaps it's this? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSUserInterfaceItemIdentification_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/NSUserInterfaceItemIdentification/identifier

Comment: That did it!  Many thanks - it won't let me award the +500 for 17 hours, so please remind me if I forget.